# Split python module without refactoring all usages

Tags: python, python-import

Assume I have a python module heavy_module.py which defines:

```
from foo.bar import heavy_dependency

class A:
 ...

class B:
 ...

# etc
class HeavyClass:
 def init:
   self.x = heavy_dependency()

def top_level_foo(bar):
  ...

x = top_level_foo(some_value)
```

now in other files in the project I have:

```
from heavy_module import A, B
```

or

```
from heavy_module import x, top_level_foo
```

or any other combination. However some places import `HeavyClass`. My goal is to split `heavy_module.py` into 2 parts to have resulting binaries smaller: lightweight classes and heavyweight classes (which rely on heavy_dependency). However I don't want to change imports of classes/methods from heavy_module.

Is there a way to introduce `light_module.py`, import it somehow to `heavy_module.py` and keep all external imports the way they are?

Comment: `from heavy_module import A, B` will process the whole of the module even if you only use `A` and `B`

Comment: @alani true. However I can later go and change it to `light_module import A, B` file by file, rather than all at once

Comment: Provide your directory structure for keeping these files.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward, you can just create a `light_module.py`, move whatever you want into it, and import it into `heavy_module`:

```
# heavy_module.py
from light_module import A, B, x, y
```

Now you can `from heavy_module import A` or `from light_module import A` and both will work.

---

If you want to be a bit more "structured" in your separation, you could also convert `heavy_module` into a package:

```
src/
└── heavy_module/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── heavy_stuff.py
    └── light_stuff.py
```

Then you can import everything into `__init__.py` from both:

```
# __init__.py
from heavy_stuff import X, Y, Z
from light_stuff import A, B, C
```

And for individual imports you could do: `from heavy_module.light_stuff import A`

Comment: sure:) Is there a way to import all classes/methods from light_module without listing them?

Comment: from light_module import *

will import all public objects

Comment: @NikitaTook You can do `from light_module import *` and all public names will be imported; it's just generally considered better practice to be explicit about what you're importing.